# GHC IO compilation error

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a problem compiling the following code on GHC 6.12.3 and I don't understand why.

The purpose of function `test2` is to return a function that uses an integer to get a string element from a list (the list is created from the first nodes from a pair-list).

The IO bits is needed as `test2` is used by another function using IO.

```
type PairList = [(String, String)]

test1 :: [String] -> Int -> String
test1 list x = list !! x

test2 :: PairList -> IO (Int -> String)
test2 pl = do
    f <- [fst x | x <- pl] :: IO [String]
    return test1 f
```

GHC gives me this error:

```
Test.hs:8:6:
    Couln't match expected type 'IO [String]'
        against inferred type '[a]'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
        f <- [fst x | x <- pl] :: IO [String]
    In the expression:
        do { f <- [fst x | x <- pl] :: IO [String];
            return test1 f }
            ...
```

Comment: You have it backwards.  `IO` functions can use pure functions, but pure functions cannot use `IO` functions.

Comment: Also, no-one mentioned it but `return test1 f` doesn't mean `return (test1 f)`, to get that you should write it as such, or use `return $ test1 f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
If you want to do this directly (you need extra IO while computing `test2`), you can do something like

```
test2 :: PairList -> IO (Int -> String)
test2 pl = do
     putStrLn "Hi Mum!"
     return (test1 [fst x | x <- pl])
```

Your original code didn't work because when you did `f <- [...]`, you were using the list monad as if it were the IO monad.

Purely as an example, you can use that like this:

```
myactions = do
   putStrLn "Please enter a list of (String,String) pairs:"
   pl <- readLn -- which you'd have to write, or derive Read and use readLn
   f <- test2 pl
   putStrLn "please enter a number:"
   n <- readLn
   putStrLn $ f n
```

Which would give you behaviour like

```
*Main> myactions
Please enter a list of (String,String) pairs:
[("hi","yes"),("oops","bye")]
Hi Mum!
please enter a number:
1
oops
```

---

**Original answer:**

I don't think you need the `IO` bits:

```
type PairList = [(String, String)]

test1 :: [String] -> Int -> String
test1 list x = list !! x

test2pure :: PairList -> (Int -> String)
test2pure pl = test1 [fst x | x <- pl]
```

This compiles fine, and gives results like

```
test2pure [("a String","ignored"), ("Another String","bye!")] 0
"a String"
```

If you want to use it in IO, you could use it like this:

```
myactions = do
   pl <- readLn
   let chosen = test2pure pl 3
   putStrLn ("3: " ++ chosen)
```

Or you could write

```
test2IO :: PairList -> Int -> IO String
test2IO pl n = return (test2pure pl n)
```

Comment: Sry forgot to explain that i need the IO bits for other reasons.

Comment: yes the new edit is exactly what I am looking for as I need to keep the function declaration `test2 :: PairList -> IO (Int -> String)` intact. However I get a new error when using your solution: `Couldn't match expected type 't1 -> t' against inferred type 'IO (Int -> String)`. Am I using it wrong? I.e. like this: `test2 [("Hi", "Hi again")] 0`

Comment: Yes, you have to get the function then apply it separately, since it has type `IO (Int -> String)`. See my edit. What else did you want to do in `test2`?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `IO ()` as a return type you can fix the compile error like this:

```
test2 pl = return $ test1 [fst x | x <- pl]
```

As AndrewC said in his answer, you probably don't need monads in this function.